# Generators of $I$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $p$ be prime and $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Prove $I=\{f(X,Y)| f(a,b)\equiv 0 \mod p\}$ can be generated by three explicit elements.

Hilbert's Theorem tells me that $I$ must really be finitely generated because $\mathbb{Z}$ is principal, hence Noetherian.

However, the proof of Hilbert's Theorem asks for too many polynomials in order to conclude this, so I believe we must not simply copy Hilbert's Theorem's proof.

In the case, $a$ and be $b$ are congruent to $0$, I was able to show $I=(p)+(X)+(Y)$.

In the case $a\equiv0$ and $b$ is invertible, I have $(p)+(x)\subseteq I$, but there are certain elements which are not spanned by these two...

Finally, for the case both of them are invertible I am clueless.

Comment: Have you tried $(p) + (X-a) + (Y-b)$?

Comment: I have not! Thank you for the suggestion. Question, how did you think of that?

Comment: $X-a$ is $0$ when you plug in for $X$ and $Y-b$ is $0$ when you plug in for $Y.$ This means $X$ and $Y$ are accounted for, so all we need is $p$ for the constant term and as it turns out nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $(p)+(X-a)+(Y-b) \subseteq I.$ For the other direction, suppose $f \in I$ and write $f(X,Y) = \sum\limits c_{ij} (X-a)^i (Y-b)^j$ for some coefficients $c_{ij}.$

Comment: If $f(X,Y)\in I$, we have $f=\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}X^i Y^j$ and $\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}a^i b^j=pK$. It doesn't seem very clear to me how we could write these new coefficients $c_{ij}$...

Comment: Write $g(X,Y) := f(X+a, Y+b)$ in the plain $X$ and $Y,$ now you can shift back to $f.$

Comment: @Kadmos if you don't want to work explicitly, you can try the following approach. Setting $J := \langle p, X-a, Y-b\rangle$, observe that $J$ is maximal, since $\mathbb{Z}[X, Y]/J \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Since $I$ is proper (it doesn't contain $1$, for example), $J$ is maximal, and $I$ contains $J$, we must have $I = J$.